# Itemize with a variable number of parameters using xparse

Tags: macros, xparse

I'm trying to write a `command` that gives an itemlist (`itemize`) which takes a variable number of parameters: It can accept up to 3 parameters, but should be able to work similarly with 1 or 2 parameters. This means that only the first parameters is mandatory while the second and last are optional.

```
\documentclass{article}

% customize sections style
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\customitemize}{moo}{
    \begin{itemize}
        \item #1
        \IfNoValueT{#2} {\item #2}
        \IfNoValueT{#3} {\item #3}
    \end{itemize}
}

\begin{document}
    \customitemize{parameter1}{parameter2}{parameter3}
    \customitemize{parameter1}{parameter2}
    \customitemize{parameter1}
\end{document}
```

The issue I have with the code above is that even if the second and third parameters are not given, it outputs a `No-Value` which obviously isn't what I was looking to get. I can't tell what's the problem with the previous code from its results:

[image: scrreenshot]

Comment: Arguments defined with `o` should be in brackets `[...]`, not in braces `{...}`. Also the test is wrong, it should be `\IfValueT` or `\IfNoValueF`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arguments defined with `o` should be enclosed in brackets `[...]`, not braces.

```
\documentclass{article}

% customize sections style
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\customitemize}{moo}{%
  \begin{itemize}
  \item #1
  \IfValueT{#2} {\item #2}
  \IfValueT{#3} {\item #3}
  \end{itemize}
}

\begin{document}

\customitemize{parameter1}[parameter2][parameter3]

\customitemize{parameter1}[parameter2]

\customitemize{parameter1}

\end{document}
```

Note that your test is wrong: it should be `\IfValueT`.

You might define the arguments with `mgg` and the braces notation would be the right one, but I'd not recommend it.

Much better:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\customitemize}{m}
 {
  \begin{itemize}
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 } { \item ##1 }
  \end{itemize}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\customitemize{parameter1, parameter2, parameter3}

\customitemize{parameter1, parameter2}

\customitemize{parameter1}

\end{document}
```